# Does time in an incubator as a newborn have long lasting effects?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, infant, birth

Are children who were born and then were in an  incubator *normal* compared to children who weren't? I ask because I was. How many children were in an incubator in the past (from 1980 to now)?

Comment: How do you define _normal_? Physically? Mentally? As infants or 30 years later?

Comment: I mean in all ways what you said.